# Fill in the hollow Spheres - generate solid spheres

Tags: graphics3d, filling

I'd like to generate microstructures of composite materials and I use an algorithm to find the centers of the spheres knowing also the radius.

My problem is that I only want  solid spheres in order to export in a next step this file in .obj type and then in .vtk type.

Does anyone know how to make the spheres solid in the whole sphere's volume?

The plot code I use is the next one:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[X, r]}, PlotRange -> {{0, L}, {0, L}, {0, L}}, Lighting -> Automatic]
```

where X corresponds to the center of the spheres.

Here is an example of my microstructure:

[image]

Comment: `Ball[X,r]`  is a solid.

Comment: This [Compute Lattice Packing Densities:New in Wolfram Language 12](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/math-entities/compute-lattice-packing-densities.html?product=mathematica) seems relevant.

Comment: @cvgmt Ball gives the same result

Comment: @TimLaska Thanks both of you for the quick response, but I forgot to say that I have downloaded the 11.3 version and as I tried the RegionPlot3D command I had the same problem because the spheres looked solid but when I exported in obj type, again looked hollow inside

Comment: Could you please let me know how to generate the microstructure you show in the first figure?
I am trying to do the same, but I am now still stuck at this problem.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Tim Laska Provide the advice.

```
centers = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {10, 3}];
unitball[c_, x_] := EuclideanDistance[c, x] <= 1;
regs = Show[
  RegionPlot3D[
     unitball[#, {x, y, z}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
     Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] & /@ centers]
Export["test.obj",regs]
```

Or use `Ball[]` and `RegionMember`

```
centers = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {10, 3}];
Table[RegionPlot3D[
    RegionMember[Ball[center], {x, y, z}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
     1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], {center, centers}] // Show;
Export["test.obj", %]
```

[image]

Another way maybe work.

```
centers = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4, 3}];
cuboid = Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}];
balls = DiscretizeRegion /@ Ball /@ centers;
newballs = RegionIntersection[#, cuboid] & /@ balls // Quiet;
regs = Show[DeleteCases[newballs, _EmptyRegion]]
```

[image]

Comment: `BoundaryStyle -> None`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @CharisSideris Do you have other question about this answer?

Comment: No thanks! I solved the problem I had, with your help

Answer (score 1):

Version 13 introduced CSGRegion as an alternative for operations such as RegionDifference. Is that useful for your application?

```
centers = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4, 3}];
cuboid = Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}];
balls = Ball /@ centers;
CSGRegion["Intersection", {CSGRegion["Union",balls], cuboid}]
```

which gives regions like [image: this region]